# KendoUI MVVM - Escaping template definitions

Tags: html, visual-studio-2013, kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm

Is there another way to format this type of kendoUI template definition instead of escaping the HTML characters? If the forward slash is not escaped the visual studio editor complains and the kendoUI library throws an exception.

```
<div id="ordersToolbar"
     data-role="toolbar"
     data-items="[
                   {'template': '<label>Order Actions<&#47label>'},
                   {'type':'separator' },
                   {'type':'button','text':'Close','id':'closeButton' }
                 ]">
</div>
```

Using a template definition not working with this syntax:

```
    <div id="ordersToolbar"
     data-role="toolbar"
     data-items="[
                  {'template':'#=$("#orderActions").html()#'},
                  {'type':'separator' },
                  {'type':'button','text':'Close','id':'closeButton' }
                 ]">
    </div>


    <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="orderActions">
        <label>Order Actions</label>
     </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problems using "/" to be honest... Nor in Visual studio neither in jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/fusebosiye/1/edit?html,js,output

Updated solution, after your edit:
http://jsbin.com/wusibadisa/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks for confirming it works. I have ReSharper integrated into my VS IDE and it reformatted some of the markup causing the issue.  Do you happen to know how to make this work using a template definition?  I updated my initial question above.

Comment: Try with:  {'template': $('#orderActions').html() }